# How can I stop Atom from starting a comment with #?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, atom-editor

I'm trying to execute this code but ATOM IDE treats # as start of comment

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Nom FROM edifice WHERE nextAffect='x' AND CI='EDIFICE # Comptabilité'");
$stmt->execute();
```

I've tried prepared statements not working.

Also the query is correct I tried it on phpmyadmin.

[snippet of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHWxb.png)

Comment: Maybe a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: have you tried this: \# instead of # ?